# create flyout menu using select option elements

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

Have this simple structure:

```
<select>
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option2</option>
  <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option4</option>
  <option>Option5</option>
  <option>Option6</option>
  <option>Option7</option>
  <option>Option8</option>
  <option>Option9</option>
</select>
```

Now, I am required to take Option3, Option4, Option5 and Option6 and place them under one single option with flyout menu style like this:

[image]

So as you can see from above I could do this using list item, but existing code is using option element and I want to do minimal changes to the structure. Of course if it can't be avoided I would go with it but just curious if I could do the same with select/option.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<select>` cannot do this. You'll need to use a menu library that renders its own HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu {
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}

.option {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  line-height:24px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  padding:5px 10px;
}

.option:hover {
  background:#a0a0a0;
}

.option:nth-child(3){
  position:relative;
}

.menu2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:200px;
  width:100px;
  top:0;
  display:none;
}

.option:nth-child(3):hover .menu2 {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="option">Option 1</div>
  <div class="option">Option 2</div>
  <div class="option">New
    <div class="menu2">
      <div class="option">Option 3</div>
      <div class="option">Option 4</div>
      <div class="option">Option 5</div>
      <div class="option">Option 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">Option 7</div>
  <div class="option">Option 8</div>
  <div class="option">Option 9</div>
</div>
```